# Country specific street address formatting in java

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

I have the different parts of an street address in separate fields (street, city, postcode, county, country,...). Now I would like to generate address labels using a specific locale.

E.g. US:
street
city, county postcode

or AT:
street
postcode city

Is there a library available for Java which can do the formatting? Something like ICU4J for numbers.

I already found some geocoding solutions doing the formatting, but they all used webservices available online. I need a solution not depending on internet access.

Comment: which webservices have you found?